# Delete a node from a singly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, time-complexity

I have this question : 
You are given a singly linked list L where each node in L stores an integer key, and a pointer to the next node in L. The last node has its next node set to NULL.
You are given a pointer ptr to a node storing key k, which is not the last node in the list.
Show how to delete the key k from the list given ptr the pointer to the node that contains k; your algorithm should have time complexity O(1), i.e., it should be independent of the length of the list. Assume you have pointers to the head and tail nodes of L.

I know that if we have a doubly linked list we can delete the node in O(1) time complexity, 
but how can we do it in singly linked list? 
don't we have to iterate over all the list in order to find the node just before it?

Comment: I guess this is an assignment. If so, don't cheat: review the course material and the answer will be straightforward. It's like 3 lines of C code and I won't give you the answer unless you have a _specific_ problem with code _you_ wrote.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo first it is not an assignment , i have a midterm next week and i was trying to solve some extra problems.. Second i wouldn't post this question unless i had a really hard time trying to solve it .. these are my thought : if i had a doubly linked list , in order to delete an element having a pointer to its node , i can simply just do the following : ptr->previous->next = ptr->next ;  but this is not the case in singly linked list!

Comment: @aschepler I'm starting to think the same :(

Comment: Here is a clue: @aschepler is right. It's not possible to solve it in O(1), because you need to search the previous node in O(n) (you can't get it directly from the node pointer). But you can solve it in O(n): first you find the preceding node, then you get the following one in O(1), and remove like you would in a double linked list.

Comment: Oh so it is in linear time :( so it can't help me

Comment: @HusseinHammoud: Its linear. But so is deleting a node from a doubly linked list. The linear part in both algorithms is finding the node. Once you have the correct node deleting it is always O(1). So you are not looking for a way to find the previous element; you are looking for a way to modify your algorithm that finds the node (so when you find the correct node you also find the previous node at the same time).

Comment: @LokiAstari No if we have the pointer to the node then it is not linear .. we just go for the node .. in doubly linked list we can go to the previous just by using the previous pointer , however in singly linked list this is not possible .. Thanks to slider I understood how to do it :)

Comment: @HusseinHammoud: You are missing the point. You still have to find the node. The problem is you found the wrong node. If you always work with pointers that are the previous node then you don't need to go back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider A -> B -> C -> D as your linked list, and let's say we have to remove B. 'ptr' is pointing to B.

1. Swap data between ptr and ptr.next. Now the list is A -> C -> B -> D
2. make ptr.next point to ptr.next.next, making the list A -> C -> D

For the edge cases, this might fail. If 'ptr' is the first node, you just need to make head point to ptr.next. But if it's the last node, you can't move the tail 'back', so in that case you'll have to traverse the list and keep track of the previous node.

Answer (score 0):

I know, how to do it for Stack (LIFO) - insert/delete with **O(1)**

If you don't mind, that data will be backwards, then you can add last item like first.

Example:

*`list.insert(1)`*

`list.insert(2)`

`list.insert(3)`

in regular way will be in list like this: `(1,2,3)`
but if you need **O(1)** then it will be like this: `(3,2,1)` - then the last item will be on position 1, so delete will be something like this (ruby code)

```
def delete
    @head = @head.next 
end
```